# Use ArchUnit As Adapter to Run Architecture Test Based on External AnalyzeClasses

Tags: java, unit-testing, archunit

I am trying to do one example with `ArchUnit` where passing the **AnalyzeClasses** can be dynamic based on for which Adapter Application the test need run.

For Example:

```
@AnalyzeClasses(packages = "${archtest.scan.package}", importOptions = { ImportOption.DoNotIncludeTests.class, ImportOption.DoNotIncludeJars.class })
public class ArchitectureTests {

}
```

And from `application.properties` file it should allow to pass the packages to analyze dynamically,  so any application using this Application as Jar library can provide the scan classes in its properties file. As below.

```
archtest.scan.package=com.example.pkgname
```

I am not sure what is the right way to pick up the dynamic value from property and pass that into `@AnalyzeClasses` Annotation. I am looking for some help or any example in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that [ArchUnit's JUnit 4 & 5 support](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_junit_4_5_support) – in the current version 0.23.1 – allows for dynamic packages configured via an `application.properties`.

But instead of using `@AnalyzeClasses`, you can always just invoke [`new ClassFileImporter().import`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/importer/ClassFileImporter.html)… and pass any dynamic runtime values you like.
(Note that ArchUnit's JUnit support also introduces a clever cache to reuse imported `JavaClasses` by multiple `@ArchTest`s, but storing `JavaClasses` in a static field  may be also good enough.)

Comment: @Mandar Pandit, did this answer help to solve your issue, or do you have further questions?

Answer (score 0):

This actually should be possible using a custom `LocationProvider` within `@AnalyzeClasses`. E.g.

```
@AnalyzeClasses(locations = ApplicationPropertiesLocationProvider.class)
public class ExampleTest {
  // ...
}

class ApplicationPropertiesLocationProvider implements LocationProvider {
  @Override
  public Set<Location> get(Class<?> testClass) {
    String packageToScan = readFromApplicationProperties();
    return Locations.ofPackage(packageToScan);
  }
}
```

But be aware of caching limitations! The caching mechanism assumes that your `LocationProvider` is "idempotent", i.e. it always returns the same locations. The caching mechanism will only take the type of the `LocationProvider` into consideration as cache key. This should not be a problem for a static `application.properties` as source though.